# Open layer properties dialog with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer, properties

When I have an object `lyr` of class `QgsMapLayer`, say `iface.activeLayer()` is there a way to open the layer properties dialog for that layer `lyr` at a specific tab, for example "Labels" using PyQGIS?

Something like `lyr.openPropertiesDialog(currentTab = 'Labels')`?

`iface.actionLayerProperties().trigger()` opens the dialog (for the active layer presumably), so I could use `iface.setActiveLayer(lyr)` before. But can I open it at a specific tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called [`QgisInterface::showLayerProperties`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a21f362ff88edec79d04919de34377087) to achieve exactly that. It expects a `QgsMapLayer` as first argument and a string identifying a page as second argument. All the available page names are listed in the documentation.

So in your example case to open the 'labels' tab it would be:

```
iface.showLayerProperties(iface.activeLayer(), 'mOptsPage_Labels')
```

`iface.actionLayerProperties().trigger()` does nothing else than invoking `showLayerProperties` on the active layer without specifying a page.